# Link to user edit form within a GUI made menu

Tags: 8, routes

I have a menu created through `admin/structure/menu`.  I would like to add a link to the logged in users edit profile.

I am attempting to do this via `module.links.menu.yml` but it is not working.  The following two iterations are at least throwing errors, previous iterations did not throw errors or add the item to the menu.  The errors are thrown when I visit `admin/structure/menu/manage/account`

Note that I'm only using the `account` for `menu_name` during testing.

```
dashboard.agent.edit:
  title: 'A new edit link'
  route_name: entity.user.edit_form
  menu_name: 'account'
  route_parameters: {user: ''}
```

This one throws the error `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\InvalidParameterException: Parameter "user" for route "entity.user.edit_form" must match "\d+" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.`

```
dashboard.agent.edit:
  title: 'A new edit link'
  route_name: entity.user.edit_form
  menu_name: 'account'
```

This one throws: `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException: Some mandatory parameters are missing ("user") to generate a URL for route "entity.user.edit_form"`

Am I missing something that would allow me to accomplish this?  Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am running into a similar problem.

Comment: I don't think so, I can't recall exactly what I did.  I just searched the codebase for `menu_name: 'account'` and `route_parameters: {user: ''}` and they weren't found.  Again, not sure, sorry.

Comment: You need to specify the user ID somehow. Your second error is saying that the user param you omitted is mandatory, the first error is saying that the argument you give for the user must match "\d+" (one or more digits, i.e. a numeric user ID). You might need to add the link programmatically, so that you can substitute in the current users ID.